# Operation order sum vs addition

Tags: arithmetic, operator-algebras

As a reader seeing an equation like
$$
\sum_{i=1}^3 1+1
$$
(as "everybody" writes it without parenthesis)

Is it

1. Sum before Addition: $\sum_{i=1}^3 1+1=\left(\sum_{i=1}^3 1\right)+1=4$
2. Addition before Sum: $\sum_{i=1}^3 1+1=\sum_{i=1}^3 \left(1+1\right)=6$

Sometimes it is imho used even conversely

- $\sum_{i=1}^3 i+1$ is often assumed to be $\left(\sum_{i=1}^3 i\right)+1=7$
- however $\sum_{i=1}^3 1+i$ can only be calculated as: $\sum_{i=1}^3 \left(1+i\right)=9$

---

Update:
Let's take an realistic example from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interatomic_potential#Functional_form

$$
V_\mathrm{TOT} = \sum_{i}^N V_1(\vec r_i) + \sum_{i,j}^N V_2(\vec r_i,\vec r_j) + \sum_{i,j,k}^N V_3(\vec r_i,\vec r_j,\vec r_k) + \cdots
$$

is it

1. $V_\mathrm{TOT} = \left[\sum_{i}^N V_1(\vec r_i)\right] + \left[\sum_{i,j}^N V_2(\vec r_i,\vec r_j)\right] + \left[\sum_{i,j,k}^N V_3(\vec r_i,\vec r_j,\vec r_k)\right] + \cdots$
2. $V_\mathrm{TOT} = \sum_{i}^N \left(V_1(\vec r_i) + \sum_{j}^N \left[V_2(\vec r_i,\vec r_j) + \sum_{k}^N \left\{V_3(\vec r_i,\vec r_j,\vec r_k) + \cdots\right\}\right]\right)$

I know the answer:
$$V_\mathrm{TOT} = \left[\sum_{i}^N V_1(\vec r_i)\right] + \left[\sum_{i=1}^{N-1} \sum_{j=i+1}^N  V_2(\vec r_i,\vec r_j)\right] + \left[\sum_{i}^{N-2} \sum_{j=i+1}^{N-1} \sum_{k=j+1}^N V_3(\vec r_i,\vec r_j,\vec r_k)\right] + \cdots$$

It is very often that someone writes $\sum_{i=1}^3 a_i+\sum_{j=1}^3 b_j$, letting the reader decide if b_1,b_2,b_3 should be counted once or three times.

As a writer I could make parantheses, but as a reader I can't.

---

Update2:

- In $\sum_i A_i + \sum_j a_{ij}$ most would assume $\sum_i \left[A_i + \sum_j a_{ij}\right]$
- but in $\sum_i A_i + \sum_j a_{j}$ most would assume $\left[\sum_i A_i\right] + \sum_j a_{j}$

I think equations should not be inperpreted differently based on there use, I think any valid form of equation should be unambiguous.

Comment: As always if an expression is ambiguous use parenthesis. We generally assume that the sum encompasses all what's in the right unless is another sum symbol. Prefer writing $1+\sum$ than $\sum+1$ to avoid possible confusion, but there is no fixed rule really, just use parenthesis.

Comment: Here nobody uses paranthesis in scientific articles, and if I would use those any co-author/supervisor would just tell me to remove them.

Let's look at any random Wikipedia-page:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interatomic_potential#Functional_form
$V_\mathrm{TOT} = \sum_{i}^N V_1(\vec r_i) + \sum_{i,j}^N V_2(\vec r_i,\vec r_j) + \sum_{i,j,k}^N V_3(\vec r_i,\vec r_j,\vec r_k) + \cdots$

Nobody uses them, it is imho keep to the reader to interpret it how the parenthesis should be set.

Comment: "the sum emcompasses ... **unless it is another sum symbol**", well the example you show me falls in this category.

Comment: @zwim Sorry for not reading your original post carefully. However in $\sum_i \sum_j a_{ij}$ the first sum emcopasses the second one and even in $\sum_i A_i +\sum_j a_{ij}$ it is clear that the first does also emcompasses the second one, because the second one has both indizes.

Answer (score 4):

> $$ \sum_{i=1}^3 1+1 $$ Is it
>
> 1. Sum before Addition: $\sum_{i=1}^3 1+1=\left(\sum_{i=1}^3 1\right)+1=4$
> 2. Addition before Sum: $\sum_{i=1}^3 1+1=\sum_{i=1}^3 \left(1+1\right)=6$

It is actually 3. Confusing and unclear.

---

There is no established rule about how far the summation operator reaches. The most important reason is that usually, when we are summing something like $$\sum_{i=1}^3 a_i$$
the expression $a_i$ **depends on the value of $i$**, and if we are careful so as not to overload the variable $i$, it should be clear that basically, the summation operator reaches as far as is needed so that the expression makes sense. For example,

$$\sum_{i=1}^3 i + i$$ doesn't make sense if it is interpreted as $$\left(\sum_{i=1}^3 i\right) + i$$ because the value of $i$ is then left hanging.

I would say most of the time, the sum ends at the first $+$ symbol, so in your case, I would say that, if you force them to decide, most mathematicians will say the result is $4$.

But most mathematicians will likely first say that this is a needlessly unclear way of writing the sum, and will tell you to either use parentheses or reorder the sum to make it clear. For example,

$$1 + \sum_{i=1}^3 1$$  is unambiguously equal to $4$.

Comment: In your last formula, I think you meant $\sum 1$ rather than $\sum i$.

Comment: @5xum I totally agree, but "nobody" writes paranthesis. Of course as a writer I would write the 1 at the beginning, but if the 1 is not 1 but a sum itself, you have the same problem: $\sum a_i +\sum b_j$, you can't switch around.

Comment: @JoKalliauer: Yes, that's exactly what I pointed out. If you look at the edit history, you'll see that it was initially mistyped as $\sum i$.